# How to write entire dataframe into mySql table in R

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have a data frame containing columns 'Quarter' having values like "16/17 Q1", "16/17 Q2"... and 'Vendor' having values like "a", "b"...  .

I am trying to write this data frame into database using

```
query <- paste("INSERT INTO cc_demo (Quarter,Vendor) VALUES(dd$FY_QUARTER,dd$VENDOR.x)")
```

but it is throwing error :

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
```

could not run statement: Unknown column 'dd$FY_QUARTER' in 'field list'

I am new to Rmysql, Please provide me some solution to write entire dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against writing sql query when you can actually use very handy functions such as `dbWriteTable` from the `RMySQL` package. But for the sake of practice, below is an example of how you should go about writing the sql query that does multiple inserts for a `MySQL` database:

```
# Set up a data.frame
dd <- data.frame(Quarter = c("16/17 Q1", "16/17 Q2"), Vendors = c("a","b"))

# Begin the query
sql_qry <- "insert into cc_demo (Quarter,Vendor) VALUES"

# Finish it with
sql_qry <- paste0(sql_qry, paste(sprintf("('%s', '%s')", dd$Quarter, dd$Vendors), collapse = ","))
```

You should get:

```
"insert into cc_demo (Quarter,Vendor) VALUES('16/17 Q1', 'a'),('16/17 Q2', 'b')"
```

You can provide this query to your database connection in order to run it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

To write a data frame to mySQL DB you need to:

1. **Create a connection to your database**, you need to specify:

   - MySQL connection
   - User
   - Password
   - Host
   - Database name

---

```
library("RMySQL")
connection <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = 'password', host = 'localhost', dbname = 'TheDB')
```

---

2. **Using the connection create a table and then export data to the database**

---

```
dbWriteTable(connection, "testTable", testTable)
```

You can overwrite an existing table like this:

```
dbWriteTable(connection, "testTable", testTable_2, overwrite=TRUE)
```