# Loading data from a dataframe in R to multiple tables in MySQL with the same name but different schema name

Tags: mysql, r

I have this `df` in `R` with various columns such as ID, Name, Prod, and other stuff which is not important. The only important thing is the IDs. In this `df` there are various rows with the same ID that has the same names as the schemas that I want to update in `MySQL`. Lets say this is the table:

| ID | Name | Prod | otherstuff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ttt637 | jj | Q2 | ghafdj... |
| ttt637 | bf | Q4 | jhsdf... |
| ttt637 | cj | Q1 | jhfdl... |
| klm457 | jj | Q2 | jshfd... |
| klm457 | lk | Q4 | uiepc... |
| klm457 | wt | Q1 | qapfn.. |
| .. for all 100+ **ID schemas** |  |  |  |

As I mentioned the schemas have the same names as IDs in the dataframe. However in the schemas there is a table called `info`; so we have: `ttt637.info`, `klm457.info` and 100+.

What I want to do is I want to update the `.info` table in the 100+ schemas in `MySQL` based on the single dataframe in `R` but assign the stuff related to each `ID` to all the 100+ `schemas.info` tables. Please note that there might be some information already available in some `schemas.info` tables, so in case there is value there that need to be updated as well.

I need to automate the whole procedure using a for loop or a function.

Could someone please help with how I could manage to do that?

I know for one schema I could use something like this [How to write entire dataframe into mySql table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466031/how-to-write-entire-dataframe-into-mysql-table-in-r) but not sure about multiple schemas.

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to do this for 1 schema manually? Can you include the code for that?

Comment: I guess for just one schema we could use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466031/how-to-write-entire-dataframe-into-mysql-table-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186839/writing-the-data-frame-to-mysql-db-table but I don't know what to do in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PhD supervisor helped me figure out how to do this. Basically he wrote:

```
for ID_loop in info$ID {
print(ID_loop)
whattoinsert <- info %>% select(ID) %>% distinct()
query = paste("USE schemas.info",
               ID_loop,
               sep = " ")
print(query)
results <- DBI:dbGetQuery(con,query)
dbWriteTable(con, "info",whattoinsert,overwrite = TRUE)
 }
```

Kudus to him :)